# Не могу указать относительный путь к файлу, который лежит в соседнем каталоге

Tags: html, linux, ос

На хостинг-сервере (ОС Cloudlinux) в корневом каталоге есть 2 соседных каталога- public_html и images. В images есть файл alpha.png а в public_html файл index.html.
В index.html пишу:

```
<div id="head">
     <img src="../images/alpha.png" alt="picture 1" height="60px">
</div>
```

но рисунок не загружается.

".." значит что надо выходить в предыдущий каталог т.е. в корневом,потом  надо заходить в папке images и найти файл alpha.png.

p.s. Если каталог images и файл index.html находятся рядом в одном public_html каталоге тогда этот код работает:

```
 <div id="head">
         <img src="images/alpha.png" alt="picture 1" height="60px">
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя, ИМХО, папка images находится вне каталога, указанного как RootDirectory для сайта. Проверь.

Comment: Andrew, смотрите фото добавил

Comment: Так и есть, у Вас папка images находится вне корневой директории сайта. У вас Apache не пускает вас на уровень выше директории public_html. переместите папку images в папку  public_html или, если для вас принципиально расположение папки images именно там, где она сейчас у Вас находится, просто создайте символьную ссылку на нее в каталоге public_html

Comment: Странно! А я думал что корневая директория та которая на самом верху то есть  /home/edelin а public_html и images являются соседными.
Вы имеете ввиду обычный линк создать в public_html?

Comment: `ln -s ~/images ~/public_html/images`

Comment: и да, каталог `public_html` является корневой директорией сайта, а каталог `/home/edelin` домашним каталогом Вашей учетной записи на сервере

Comment: Andrew, всё понял. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1):

public_html и есть корневой каталог для твоего основного домена. Все файлы и каталоги, включая images должны находится внутри.
../ не работает, потому что ты пытаешь выйти не в корневой каталог, а за его пределы.

p.s. Твой вариант из p.s. правильный.

Comment: Sjeurt, смотрите фото добавил